# parseFloat to display with comma

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to use the below JavaScript code to use comma's? For example the `var num = 1924.00` Is there way to get it to display as 1,924.00?

```
var num = parseFloat(totalAmount).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: You can do it like this `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(yourNumber))` its already built in your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a specific regex like this one in the function below:

```
function format_currency( value ) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

If you want to use it in conjuction with the .toFixed(), just do like this:

```
format_currency( 1245.3.toFixed(2) );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice copy-pasta

Comment: No, just part of a set of functions I use in my js lib for currencies. Hard to belive uhm?

Comment: Either way, that function is in one of the answers to the duplicate question [and we try to avoid duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Hey man, I'm sorry, next time I'll do a fine research for duplicates everywhere on the web in order to help others.

Comment: Thank you @Jazzpaths your help was appreciated.

Comment: Glad for that @SteveWolfe!